# get list from axios with filter options- gets undifined

Tags: javascript, node.js

i know its a popular question but i still couldent get an asnwer.

i have an axiox get, like this

```
function query(filterBy) {
    return axios.get(TOY_URL,{ params: { filterBy } })
    .then(res=>res.data)
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Couldn\'t load toys please try again',err);
        })
}
```

on server side :

```
app.get("/api/toy", (req, res) => {
  let { filterBy } = req.query;
  if(filterBy !== undefined) filterBy=JSON.parse(filterBy)
  else{console.log('why !!');}
  toysService.query(filterBy).then((toys) => res.send(toys));
```

and next step is :

```
function query(filterBy){
    console.log(filterBy);
    const regex = new RegExp(filterBy.name, 'i')
    return Promise.resolve(
        gToys
            .filter(toy => {
                return regex.test(toy.name)
            })
            .filter(toy => {
                const s = filterBy.inStock
                return s === 'TRUE' ? toy.inStock : s === 'FALSE' ? !toy.inStock : toy
            })
            .filter(toy => {
                return toy.type.includes(filterBy.type)
            })
            .sort((a, b) => {
                if (filterBy.sortBy === 'NAME') {
                    return a.name > b.name ? 1 : a.name < b.name ? -1 : 0
                } else if (filterBy.sortBy === 'PRICE') {
                    return a.price > b.price ? 1 : a.price < b.price ? -1 : 0
                }
            })
    )
}
```

i get an error : Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

the weird part is that on all console.log on cmd , i get this :

```
{}
undefined
why !!
undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined ...

{ filterBy: '{"name":"","price":0,"type":"all","inStock":"all"}' }
{"name":"","price":0,"type":"all","inStock":"all"}
{ name: '', price: 0, type: 'all', inStock: 'all' }
```

i want to get a list (comes grom gList) even if i dont do any kind of filtering.

thank you .

Answer (score 0):

I think the query parameter maybe URL encoded